# Error gralloc Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

** I noticed that there is an error in Android monitor called "gralloc",I searched everyhwere but i didn't find nothing about this strange error,do you know what this means:
E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error the other day. I went all over the web to try to search for a solution, but found none.

I think I found out what I was doing wrong. I was initializing the same EditText View several times in the same class (MainActivity).
I fixed it by simply having to initialize the object in every method I was using it in, instead of have one global object.